# curved lower arrow?

Tags: arrows

I need to use curved arrows instead of linear ones. So instead of

```
$$A\stackrel{x}\longrightarrow B \stackrel{y}\longrightarrow C$$
```

I might want to input something like

```
$$A\myarrow{x} B \myarrow{y}C$$
```

to produce something roughly similar to this (hand-drawn in inkscape):
[image]

Is this even possible without converting my whole diagram into a Tikz drawing?

Comment: Off topic: `$$` is used in TeX, in LaTeX is used `\[` and `\]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command: Add this to your document preamble: `\newcommand{\myarrow}[1]{\raisebox{-12pt}{$\stackrel{\tikz[baseline]{\draw[->] (0, 0) arc (220:320:10pt);}}{#1}$}}`

and use it as `$A\myarrow{x}B$` and `$A\myarrow{x}B\myarrow{y}C$`.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: In amssymb, `curvearrowright` and `curvearrowleft` both form the upper half of a semicircle, with arrows in opposite directions. Are there similar commands for the lower half of a semicircle?